# TFS 2017 Can't Create a Test Plan

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to set up a Manual Test Plan in a new Team Project, but the Test area does not match the online documentation for TFS 2017.

> 3. Go to the Test hub. Create a test plan for your current sprint.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/manual-exploratory-testing/getting-started/create-a-test-plan

The Test Hub in our installation contains the following sections:
Test Plans | Runs | Machines and this does not match the Test Hub in the documentation (missing [Configurations], [Parameters], and [Load Test])

In the screenshots in the documentation, there is a "+" in the left hand pane that is missing from our installation. "Test Plans" contains

[Show tests from child suites][Expand All][Collapse All]

Assume that no explicit action has been taken to manually configure permissions. I am acting as a Collection Administrator.

Can someone help me find out how to create a Test Plan inside TFS 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the creation is in the web. First you need to **check your access level**.

> **Basic** is the default access level, to users with a TFS client access license (CAL). Basic provides access to most features, **except
>   for Test**.

So suggest you use **Stakeholder** or **VS Enterprise**  access. More detail about this check [Change access levels](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/connect/change-access-levels)

Moreover, for doing any of the test management capabilities, you need the **Test Manager Extension** or Test Pro with MSDN.

Check the below links for more information.

- https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-feature-matrix-vs
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web

Answer (score 1):

In TFS 2017, to create a test plan you need to install [Test Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web) extension for your team project collections.

It includes test planning, authoring, execution and tracking.