# How do I grant permissions to manage test plans in Azure dev-ops

Tags: azure-devops, test-plan

Problem: I do not have sufficient rights to create a test plan. I do have permission to create PBIs, and even test cases (for example by creating a link to a new item).

- For projects with an existing test plan, I cannot add test cases. The + button is simply not there.
- For projects without a test plan defined, I get a landing page with flashy images and a link to the [test manager extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web), which is completely useless, since it's not compatible with the current version of Azure dev-ops.

How do I get access?

(The same or a similar question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42676351/tfs-2017-cant-create-a-test-plan), [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31711815/how-do-i-grant-permissions-to-manage-test-plans-in-vso), [and here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48689392/what-permission-level-do-you-need-in-vsts-to-create-test-plans), and [yet again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628930/team-foundation-server-2015-cannot-create-test-plans), but microsoft insists on changing the procedure whenever there's a new stackoverflow answer.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you have a `Basic` subscription, which does not give permission to use test plans. 
This permission is included in the following subscriptions

- Visual Studio Enterprise
- Visual Studio Test Professional
- Test Manager (which as you write is deprecated)

Instead you need `Basic + Test plans` nowadays, which can be accessed from azure-devops. Though it is the cheaper option, it's still very expensive, 52 euro per user per month in Europe.

Practical tip: if there is another member with a VS Enterprise subscription, this person would be able to create a test plan and assign all tests to it (5 mins job), while any `Basic` user can create / run the test cases themselves.

If you want the `Basic + Test plans` license anyway, go to Organization settings -> Billing -> `Basic + Test plans` -> Start free trial, to get licenses. Assign the ordered licenses in Organization settings -> Users.

Now let's hope Microsoft doesn't change the flow next week...

Sources

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/manual-test-permissions?view=azure-devops#feedback
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/