# Create New Test Plan button missing from Test Plans for all users on all projects

Tags: azure-devops

Create New Test Plan button missing from Test Plans for all users on all projects
[See below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay5RY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Create New Test Plan button missing from Test Plans for all users on all projects

Generally Test plan creation is limited to users subscribed to Test Manager extension or VS/MSDN subscribers.

> Basic license users can only run tests. You need a valid Visual Studio
> subscription (Enterprise, Test Professional or MSDN Platforms) or Test
> Manager license ($52 monthly):
> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web
> to create test plans.
>
> **See this thread : [Can't add a new test plan](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/80055/cant-add-a-new-test-plan.html)**

So please check if you have the license to create the test plan, and for an **paid extension** you must assign that extension to users who need access, so they can start using that extension's capabilities. Please see [Assign paid extension access to users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/marketplace/assign-paid-extensions?view=vsts)

And check if Basic + Test Plans as free trial is expired.

Please check this thread for some more details [How do I grant permissions to manage test plans in Azure dev-ops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57377970/how-do-i-grant-permissions-to-manage-test-plans-in-azure-dev-ops).